# python dictionary build from "show port-channel summary"

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I need help with python code to dynamically build dictionary from the output of "show port-channel summary". following is sample output and dictionary.

```
switch# show port-channel summary
Flags:  D - Down        P - Up in port-channel (members)
         I - Individual  H - Hot-standby (LACP only)
         s - Suspended   r - Module-removed
         b - BFD Session Wait
         S - Switched    R - Routed
         U - Up (port-channel)
         M - Not in use. Min-links not met
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group Port-       Type     Protocol  Member Ports
       Channel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     Po1(SU)     Eth      LACP      Eth1/2(P)   Eth1/3(P)   Eth2/3(P)
                                      Eth3/3(P)   
2     Po2(RU)     Eth      LACP      Eth2/2(P)   Eth2/5(P)   
201   Po201(RD)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/1(P)
```

Need to build dictionary:

```
{
    "Po1": [Eth1/2,Eth1/3,Eth2/3,Eth3/3],
    "Po2": [Eth2/2,Eth2/5],
    "Po201": [Eth1/4,Eth1/21]

}
```

could you help with python code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` module to parse the text:

```py
import re

txt = """
switch# show port-channel summary
Flags:  D - Down        P - Up in port-channel (members)
         I - Individual  H - Hot-standby (LACP only)
         s - Suspended   r - Module-removed
         b - BFD Session Wait
         S - Switched    R - Routed
         U - Up (port-channel)
         M - Not in use. Min-links not met
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group Port-       Type     Protocol  Member Ports
       Channel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     Po1(SU)     Eth      LACP      Eth1/2(P)   Eth1/3(P)   Eth2/3(P)
                                      Eth3/3(P)   
2     Po2(RU)     Eth      LACP      Eth2/2(P)   Eth2/5(P)   
201   Po201(RD)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/1(P)   
"""

r_line = re.compile(r"^(\d+.*?\n)(?=\d+|\Z)", flags=re.S | re.M)

data = {}
for line in r_line.findall(txt):
    _, k, _, _, v = line.split(maxsplit=4)
    data[k.split("(")[0]] = [i.split("(")[0] for i in v.split()]

print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
{'Po1': ['Eth1/2', 'Eth1/3', 'Eth2/3', 'Eth3/3'], 'Po2': ['Eth2/2', 'Eth2/5'], 'Po201': ['Eth1/1']}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej. how does this logic work? any links you can share? Thanks!

Comment: @slowstack You can debug the regex I used on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Y93AMF/1). This will parse the three lines from the text - then it's just normal `str.split()` with removing of brackets '('